# Write to database from R when hit rate limit using twitteR library

Tags: r, sqlite, twitter, rate-limiting

I would really appreciate any help from the SO community: I would like to write to a database (SQLite) the results that have been returned by the code below each time the code hits the rate limit. I would be really grateful for any advice on this.

The reason I would like to write intermediate results to a database is because I run out of RAM and lose everything once I try for more than about 200,000 tweets.

Thank you for your advice!

Niall

```
require(twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth("1", "2", "3", "4")
dailyTweets <- list()
dailyTweets<- searchTwitter("", n= 1000000, geocode="53.5,-8,318km", since="2014-07-14", until="2014-07-15",retryOnRateLimit=600)
```

Comment: I am afraid you can just retrieve 1500 tweets per search...